# Get URL to a local file with SPM (Swift Package Manager)

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager

I am trying to read `.json` file in my unit test and running it within Swift Package. Using Xcode 11 and Swift 5.1

```
let path = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: "json")
// Path is nil
```

I've been told that Swift packages don't have bundles any more. So how can I workaround this?

Part of my Swift.package

```
.testTarget(
    name: "ProjectTests", 
    dependencies: [
        .target(name: "Project")
    ],
    path: "Tests",
    exclude: [
        "Folder/File.swift"
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 5):

The solution we have found is `FileManager`.

```
var cache: [String: URL] = [:] // Save all local files in this cache
let baseURL = urlForRestServicesTestsDir()

guard let enumerator = FileManager.default.enumerator(
    at: baseURL,
    includingPropertiesForKeys: [.nameKey],
    options: [.skipsHiddenFiles, .skipsPackageDescendants], 
    errorHandler: nil) else {
        fatalError("Could not enumerate \(baseURL)")
}

for case let url as URL in enumerator where url.isFileURL {
    cache[url.lastPathComponent] = url
}
```

You will need this method

```
static func urlForRestServicesTestsDir() -> URL {
    let currentFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "\(#file)", isDirectory: false)
    return currentFileURL
        .deletingLastPathComponent()
        .deletingLastPathComponent()
}
```

After this you can get URL for every file:

```
func url(for fileName: String) -> URL? {
    return cache[fileName]
}
```

In case you will only want to run this code in Swift package use `#if SWIFT_PACKAGE`.